# How to convert STIX objects to Pydantic models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI and I need to represent different STIX 2 objects (from MITRE ATT&CK)
with a corresponding/equivalent Pydantic model in order to return them as a response JSON.

Let's consider the AttackPattern object.

```
from stix2.v20.sdo import AttackPattern
```

It has the following class

```
class AttackPattern(_DomainObject):
    """For more detailed information on this object's properties, see
    `the STIX 2.0 specification <http://docs.oasis-open.org/cti/stix/v2.0/cs01/part2-stix-objects/stix-v2.0-cs01-part2-stix-objects.html#_Toc496714302>`__.
    """

    _type = 'attack-pattern'
    _properties = OrderedDict([
        ('type', TypeProperty(_type, spec_version='2.0')),
        ('id', IDProperty(_type, spec_version='2.0')),
        ('created_by_ref', ReferenceProperty(valid_types='identity', spec_version='2.0')),
        ('created', TimestampProperty(default=lambda: NOW, precision='millisecond')),
        ('modified', TimestampProperty(default=lambda: NOW, precision='millisecond')),
        ('name', StringProperty(required=True)),
        ('description', StringProperty()),
        ('kill_chain_phases', ListProperty(KillChainPhase)),
        ('revoked', BooleanProperty(default=lambda: False)),
        ('labels', ListProperty(StringProperty)),
        ('external_references', ListProperty(ExternalReference)),
        ('object_marking_refs', ListProperty(ReferenceProperty(valid_types='marking-definition', spec_version='2.0'))),
        ('granular_markings', ListProperty(GranularMarking)),
    ])

    @property
    def properties(self):
        return self._properties
```

and it is serialized to JSON in this way

```
{
    "created": "2021-04-13T12:45:26.506Z",
    "created_by_ref": "identity--c78cb6e5-0c4b-4611-8297-d1b8b55e40b5",
    "description": "An adversary may attempt to get detailed information about remote systems and their peripherals, such as make/model, role, and configuration. Adversaries may use information from Remote System Information Discovery to aid in targeting and shaping follow-on behaviors. For example, the system\u2019s operational role and model information can dictate whether it is a relevant target for the adversary\u2019s operational objectives. In addition, the system\u2019s configuration may be used to scope subsequent technique usage. Requests for system information are typically implemented using automation and management protocols and are often automatically requested by vendor software during normal operation. This information may be used to tailor management actions, such as program download and system or module firmware. An adversary may leverage this same information by issuing calls directly to the system\u2019s API.",
    "external_references": [
        {
            "external_id": "T0888",
            "source_name": "mitre-ics-attack",
            "url": "https://collaborate.mitre.org/attackics/index.php/Technique/T0888"
        }
    ],
    "id": "attack-pattern--2fedbe69-581f-447d-8a78-32ee7db939a9",
    "kill_chain_phases": [
        {
            "kill_chain_name": "mitre-ics-attack",
            "phase_name": "discovery-ics"
        }
    ],
    "modified": "2021-04-13T12:45:26.506Z",
    "name": "Remote System Information Discovery",
    "object_marking_refs": [
        "marking-definition--fa42a846-8d90-4e51-bc29-71d5b4802168"
    ],
    "type": "attack-pattern",
    "x_mitre_data_sources": [
        "Network protocol analysis",
        "Packet capture"
    ],
    "x_mitre_platforms": [
        "Safety Instrumented System/Protection Relay",
        "Field Controller/RTU/PLC/IED"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the object has also some nested objects as properties.
What is the best way to create an equivalent Pydantic model for an AttackPattern starting from the object itsel or its `__dict__` representation?

I created a simle test class to work a bit with it:

```
from stix2.v20.sdo import AttackPattern

from mitre.attack.ics.mitre_attack_ics import MitreAttackICS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mitre_attack_ics = MitreAttackICS()

    techniques: list[AttackPattern] = mitre_attack_ics.get_techniques()
    technique = techniques[0]

    print(technique.serialize(sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    # print(technique.__dict__)
    # print(technique.object_properties())
    # print(technique.properties)
```

The entire source code including the utility classes and the FastAPI are also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/FastAPI-OpenAPI/tree/mitre-attack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible and promising approach is to generate the Pydantic model starting from the corresponding JSON Schema of the STIX object.

Luckily enough the JSON schemas for all the STIX 2 objects have been defined by the *[OASIS Open](https://www.oasis-open.org/)* organization on the GitHub repository [CTI-STIX2-JSON-Schemas](https://github.com/oasis-open/cti-stix2-json-schemas).

In particular, the JSON Schema for the *Attack-Pattern* is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oasis-open/cti-stix2-json-schemas/master/schemas/sdos/attack-pattern.json).

```
{
  "$id": "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/oasis-open/cti-stix2-json-schemas/stix2.1/schemas/sdos/attack-pattern.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "attack-pattern",
  "description": "Attack Patterns are a type of TTP that describe ways that adversaries attempt to compromise targets. ",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "../common/core.json"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The type of this object, which MUST be the literal `attack-pattern`.",
          "enum": [
            "attack-pattern"
          ]
        },
        "aliases" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "description": "Alternative names used to identify this Attack Pattern."
        },
        "id": {
          "title": "id",
          "pattern": "^attack-pattern--"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name used to identify the Attack Pattern."
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "A description that provides more details and context about the Attack Pattern, potentially including its purpose and its key characteristics."
        },
        "kill_chain_phases": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "The list of kill chain phases for which this attack pattern is used.",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "../common/kill-chain-phase.json"
          },
          "minItems": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "required": [
    "name"
  ]
}
```

The project for generating Pydantic models, [**datamodel-code-generator**](https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator/), is also linked in the official [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/datamodel_code_generator/).

With the above generator I'm able to generate a Pydantic model using the following command:

```
datamodel-codegen --url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oasis-open/cti-stix2-json-schemas/master/schemas/sdos/attack-pattern.json --input-file-type jsonschema --field-constraints --field-include-all-keys --use-schema-description --base-class pydantic.BaseModel --class-name AttackPatternDTO --output domain/mitre/attack/attack_pattern_dto.py
```

The resulting class, `AttackPatternDTO`, is not perfect but not bad at all, for example it does not extend the `BaseModel` class and defines two times the properties of the `Core` class, `id` & `type`. Therefore some work is needed to fix these issues or to correct the generated code.

```
# generated by datamodel-codegen:
#   filename:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oasis-open/cti-stix2-json-schemas/master/schemas/sdos/attack-pattern.json
#   timestamp: 2021-06-11T08:38:36+00:00

from __future__ import annotations

from enum import Enum
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Union

from pydantic import AnyUrl, BaseModel, Field


class Type(Enum):
    """
    The type of this object, which MUST be the literal `attack-pattern`.
    """

    attack_pattern = 'attack-pattern'


class SpecVersion(Enum):
    """
    The version of the STIX specification used to represent this object.
    """

    field_2_0 = '2.0'
    field_2_1 = '2.1'


class Properties(BaseModel):
    __root__: Any = Field(
        ...,
        _schema='http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
        description='Rules for custom properties',
        patternProperties={
            '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{0,245}_bin$': {'$ref': '../common/binary.json'},
            '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{0,245}_hex$': {'$ref': '../common/hex.json'},
            '^([a-z][a-z0-9_]{2,249})|id$': {
                'anyOf': [
                    {'type': 'array', 'minItems': 1},
                    {'type': 'string'},
                    {'type': 'integer'},
                    {'type': 'boolean'},
                    {'type': 'number'},
                    {'type': 'object'},
                ]
            },
        },
        title='properties',
    )


class Identifier(BaseModel):
    __root__: str = Field(
        ...,
        _schema='http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
        description='Represents identifiers across the CTI specifications. The format consists of the name of the top-level object being identified, followed by two dashes (--), followed by a UUIDv4.',
        regex='^[a-z][a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9]--[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[89abAB][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$',
        title='identifier',
    )


class Timestamp(BaseModel):
    __root__: str = Field(
        ...,
        _schema='http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
        description="Represents timestamps across the CTI specifications. The format is an RFC3339 timestamp, with a required timezone specification of 'Z'.",
        regex='^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|60)(\\.[0-9]+)?Z$',
        title='timestamp',
    )


class ExternalReferenceItem(BaseModel):
    source_name: str = Field(
        ...,
        description='The source within which the external-reference is defined (system, registry, organization, etc.)',
        regex='^cve$',
    )
    external_id: str = Field(
        ...,
        description='An identifier for the external reference content.',
        regex='^CVE-\\d{4}-(0\\d{3}|[1-9]\\d{3,})$',
    )


class ExternalReferenceItem1(BaseModel):
    source_name: str = Field(
        ...,
        description='The source within which the external-reference is defined (system, registry, organization, etc.)',
        regex='^capec$',
    )
    external_id: str = Field(
        ...,
        description='An identifier for the external reference content.',
        regex='^CAPEC-\\d+$',
    )


class UrlRegex(BaseModel):
    __root__: AnyUrl = Field(
        ...,
        _schema='http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
        description='Matches a URI according to RFC 3986.',
        title='url-regex',
    )


class Dictionary(BaseModel):
    """
    A dictionary captures a set of key/value pairs
    """

    pass


class Selector(BaseModel):
    __root__: str = Field(
        ..., regex='^([a-z0-9_-]{3,249}(\\.(\\[\\d+\\]|[a-z0-9_-]{1,250}))*|id)$'
    )


class GranularMarking(BaseModel):
    """
    The granular-marking type defines how the list of marking-definition objects referenced by the marking_refs property to apply to a set of content identified by the list of selectors in the selectors property.
    """

    selectors: List[Selector] = Field(
        ...,
        description='A list of selectors for content contained within the STIX object in which this property appears.',
        min_items=1,
    )
    lang: Optional[str] = Field(
        None,
        description='Identifies the language of the text identified by this marking.',
    )
    marking_ref: Identifier


class KillChainPhase(BaseModel):
    """
    The kill-chain-phase represents a phase in a kill chain.
    """

    kill_chain_name: str = Field(..., description='The name of the kill chain.')
    phase_name: str = Field(..., description='The name of the phase in the kill chain.')


class HashesType(Dictionary):
    """
    The Hashes type represents one or more cryptographic hashes, as a special set of key/value pairs
    """

    pass


class ExternalReference1(BaseModel):
    """
    External references are used to describe pointers to information represented outside of STIX.
    """

    description: Optional[str] = Field(None, description='A human readable description')
    url: Optional[UrlRegex] = Field(
        None, description='A URL reference to an external resource.'
    )
    hashes: Optional[HashesType] = Field(
        None, description='Specifies a dictionary of hashes for the file.'
    )


class ExternalReference(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union[
        ExternalReference1,
        ExternalReferenceItem,
        ExternalReferenceItem1,
        Union[Any, Any, Any],
    ] = Field(
        ...,
        _schema='http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
        description='External references are used to describe pointers to information represented outside of STIX.',
        title='external-reference',
    )


class Core:
    """
    Common properties and behavior across all STIX Domain Objects and STIX Relationship Objects.
    """

    type: str = Field(
        ...,
        description='The type property identifies the type of STIX Object (SDO, Relationship Object, etc). The value of the type field MUST be one of the types defined by a STIX Object (e.g., indicator).',
        max_length=250,
        min_length=3,
        not_={'enum': ['action']},
        regex='^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\\-?$',
        title='type',
    )
    spec_version: SpecVersion = Field(
        ...,
        description='The version of the STIX specification used to represent this object.',
    )
    id: Identifier = Field(
        ...,
        description='The id property universally and uniquely identifies this object.',
    )
    created_by_ref: Optional[Identifier] = Field(
        None,
        description='The ID of the Source object that describes who created this object.',
    )
    labels: Optional[List[str]] = Field(
        None,
        description='The labels property specifies a set of terms used to describe this object.',
        min_items=1,
    )
    created: Timestamp = Field(
        ...,
        description='The created property represents the time at which the first version of this object was created. The timstamp value MUST be precise to the nearest millisecond.',
    )
    modified: Timestamp = Field(
        ...,
        description='The modified property represents the time that this particular version of the object was modified. The timstamp value MUST be precise to the nearest millisecond.',
    )
    revoked: Optional[bool] = Field(
        None,
        description='The revoked property indicates whether the object has been revoked.',
    )
    confidence: Optional[int] = Field(
        None,
        description='Identifies the confidence that the creator has in the correctness of their data.',
        ge=0.0,
        le=100.0,
    )
    lang: Optional[str] = Field(
        None, description='Identifies the language of the text content in this object.'
    )
    external_references: Optional[List[ExternalReference]] = Field(
        None,
        description='A list of external references which refers to non-STIX information.',
        min_items=1,
    )
    object_marking_refs: Optional[List[Identifier]] = Field(
        None,
        description='The list of marking-definition objects to be applied to this object.',
        min_items=1,
    )
    granular_markings: Optional[List[GranularMarking]] = Field(
        None,
        description='The set of granular markings that apply to this object.',
        min_items=1,
    )
    extensions: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = Field(
        None,
        description='Specifies any extensions of the object, as a dictionary.',
        minProperties=1,
        patternProperties={
            '^extension-definition--[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[89abAB][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$': {
                'allOf': [{'$ref': '../common/extension.json'}]
            }
        },
    )


class AttackPatternDTO(Core):
    """
    Attack Patterns are a type of TTP that describe ways that adversaries attempt to compromise targets.
    """

    type: Optional[Type] = Field(
        None,
        description='The type of this object, which MUST be the literal `attack-pattern`.',
    )
    aliases: Optional[List[str]] = Field(
        None, description='Alternative names used to identify this Attack Pattern.'
    )
    id: Optional[Any] = Field(None, regex='^attack-pattern--', title='id')
    name: Optional[str] = Field(
        None, description='The name used to identify the Attack Pattern.'
    )
    description: Optional[str] = Field(
        None,
        description='A description that provides more details and context about the Attack Pattern, potentially including its purpose and its key characteristics.',
    )
    kill_chain_phases: Optional[List[KillChainPhase]] = Field(
        None,
        description='The list of kill chain phases for which this attack pattern is used.',
        min_items=1,
    )
```